# Activity Remains BLACK when launching under Doze Mode

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-doze

So I have an alarm activity, that launches from a service, and **while in doze mode**, the **activity remains black** until I turn it off and on again.

Now, although the screen is black, the **views are responsive** (If I touch them, they work)

If I try to take a screenshot, I suddenly see the activity, and *if I turn the screen off and on again, everything is working as expected*.

**Videos of the weirdness:**

[Responsive black screen](https://youtu.be/jMNsTiFgZxY)

[Turn off, and on again](https://youtu.be/M7CiL3tRNmk)

[Trying to take a screenshot](https://youtu.be/0TF-dx0NXGw)

This is basically how I launch the activity:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannels.CHANNEL_ALARM_SERVICE)
...
// set intent
val alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmActivity::class.java)
alarmIntent.putExtra(IntentExtras.KEY_ID, alarm.id)
builder.setFullScreenIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, RequestCodes.REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_ACTIVITY, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), true)
...
startForeground(...)
```

This is how I unlock the screen in the Activity's onCreate method

```
public class ScreenUnlockerUtil {

public static void unlockScreen(BaseActivity activity) {

    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        // in addition to flags
        activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
        activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
        return;
    }


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) activity.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (keyguardManager != null) {
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(activity, new KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDismissError() {
                    super.onDismissError();
                    Timber.e("Keyguard Dismiss Error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismissSucceeded() {
                    super.onDismissSucceeded();
                    Timber.d("Keyguard Dismiss Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismissCancelled() {
                    super.onDismissCancelled();
                    Timber.w("Keyguard Dismiss Cancelled");
                }
            });
        }
        return;
    }


}
```

I managed to reproduce the issue with

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

I naturally can't post ALL the code, but let me know if there's anything you might need.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that `return` supposed to be there in the `O_MR1` check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return` from your if statement:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    // in addition to flags
    activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
    activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
    //return;
}
```

Comment: It seems that it's still happening, however never when I'm connected to the debug build.

Comment: Connected via debug means no doze mode, this could be why.